# YOLO performance on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

Have anyone used YOLO : Real time object detection on iOS devices ? Are there any performance metrics that are available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following posts/repos demonstrate the use of YOLO on iOS devices, and some of them include performance metrics as well:

- [Real-time object detection with YOLO](http://machinethink.net/blog/object-detection-with-yolo/)
- [YOLO: Core ML versus MPSNNGraph](http://machinethink.net/blog/yolo-coreml-versus-mps-graph/) (code at [Github](https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph))
- [Yolo for Android and iOS](https://github.com/mdietrichstein/yolo-tiny-v1-mobile)
- [Object Detection: From the TensorFlow API to YOLOv2 on iOS](http://jeffxtang.github.io/deep/learning,/cnn,/object/detection,/tensorflow,/mobile,/yolo,/yolov2/2017/07/23/object-detection-on-ios.html) (code at [Github](https://github.com/jeffxtang/yolov2_tf_ios))
- [YOLO Net on iOS](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2017/pdfs/135.pdf) (Stanford CS231 student paper)
- [Computer vision in iOS - Object detection](https://sriraghu.com/2017/07/12/computer-vision-in-ios-object-detection/)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Forge seems incredibly useful !